# How to write a query to select a row comparing by spliting a field

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I have a table with the following fields

```
+-------------+----------+
|    name     |   dob    |
+-------------+----------+
```

**name:** String. Contains both firstname and lastname

**dob:** Date: Contains full date of birth

From a Form, I am asking for the first letter of firstname and birth month. Let suppose I get them from a model as `Model.code` and `Model.BirthMonth`

I need a query to match the record in the table with first letter firstname, for this I need to split the field into multiple part as first name and last name and compare the `Model.code` with the first letter of first name.

I have no idea how to write such query.

Comment: Why do you want to split? Is the logical order <FirstName[whitespace(s)]LastName> in the field <Name> always the same?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the name contains "firstname lastname" in that order, the query would be

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE
    name LIKE '<model.code.passed.as.parameter>%'
AND DATEPART(mm, date) = <model.month.passed.as.parameter>
```

If the name is in "lastname, firstname" format, then the `WHERE` condition would be

```
    name LIKE '%, <model.code.passed.as.parameter>%'
```

and so on, based on the format of name.

Answer (score 0):

If your names are simply concatenated as `first-space-last`, `LIKE` will do it. For example, to get all rows where the (first) name starts with `'C'`:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE name LIKE 'C%'
```

If your name strings are in format `last-comma-space-first`, and the last/first separator is guaranteed to be the only comma in the string:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE name LIKE '%, C%'
```

Any other situation will require something more complicated, possibly a [user-defined function](https://sqlserverfast.com/?s=user+defined+ugly) involving [`SUBSTRING`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx), [`CHARINDEX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx), conditional statements and maybe loops.

But if that's the case, you should probably rethink the database design, and store first and last names in separate columns, because the intensive use of string functions for splitting usually means noticeable performance degradation.